# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas" error in Caffe compilation

Tags: caffe, openblas

When I was compiling Caffe, I had this error, despite OpenBLAS is installed:

```
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so] Error 1
```

Is there a solution for it?

Answer (score 13):

Including the base packs even after cloning OpenBlas and making will link the appropriate libraries in 14.04 and 16.

```
apt install liblapack-dev liblapack3 libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev
```

apt install liblapack-dev liblapack3 libopenblas-base libopenblas-dev

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem. Even adding library directory "/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/" to ldconfig cache didn't help (as my libopenblas.so is at "/opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so").

Using cmake helped me. Try this from caffe root directory:

`mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBLAS=open ..
make all
make runtest`

If you need to use make, add the symlink of libopenblas.so to /usr/lib. I did the following:

`ln -s /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/libopenblas.so /usr/lib/libopenblas.so`

Answer (score 0):

I saw the similar problem (I'm compiling caffe again for some reason).
I found the library file the builder is looking for (-lcblas or -latlas means libcblas.so and libatlas.so) are under /usr/lib64/atlas. So just added symbolic links under /usr/lib64 like this.

```
sudo ln /usr/lib64/atlas/libcblas.so.3.0 /usr/lib64/libcblas.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/atlas/libatlas.so.3.0 /usr/lib64/libatlas.so
```

But I guess more proper method is to set Makefile.config (the CBLAS path). (I thought the default path will do away with it reading the comment saying so, but it did not.) Hope this helps anyone.