# i cant update and install any packages in rstudio! here i tried to install fpc package but shows error

Tags: r

Here I tried to install fpc package but it shows error.
I know zero status just simply means error but I cant seem to find the error.
When updating, it says the `.libPath()` directory is non-writable and so I made a personal directory for storage, is that the problem?
it also shows permission denied error. I am the admin, so idk why it shows that.
another user in the same system used rstudio last day and this problem started after that. What should I do to make this right?

```r
> install.packages("fpc")
Installing package into ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘mclust’, ‘prabclus’, ‘robustbase’, ‘kernlab’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/mclust_5.4.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2873339 bytes (2.7 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.7 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/prabclus_2.3-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 191810 bytes (187 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 187 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/robustbase_0.93-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2956184 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/kernlab_0.9-29.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1168376 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/fpc_2.2-5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 198202 bytes (193 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 193 KB

* installing *source* package ‘mclust’ ...
** package ‘mclust’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dmvnorm.f -o dmvnorm.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c init.c -o init.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c mclust.f -o mclust.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c mclustaddson.f -o mclustaddson.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--sort-common -o mclust.so dmvnorm.o init.o mclust.o mclustaddson.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -lopenblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:6: mclust.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mclust’
* removing ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6/mclust’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mclust’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘robustbase’ ...
** package ‘robustbase’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c R-rng4ftn.c -o R-rng4ftn.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c eigen.f -o eigen.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c init.c -o init.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c lmrob.c -o lmrob.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c mc.c -o mc.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c monitor.c -o monitor.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c qn_sn.c -o qn_sn.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rf-common.f -o rf-common.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rffastmcd.f -o rffastmcd.o
rffastmcd.f:1036:0:

 1036 |                      if(final .or. .not.part .or.
      | 
Warning: ‘nmaxi’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rfltsreg.f -o rfltsreg.o
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rllarsbi.f -o rllarsbi.o
rllarsbi.f:72:0:

   72 |       INTEGER OUT
      | 
Warning: ‘out’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rob-utils.c -o rob-utils.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c rowMedians.c -o rowMedians.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c wgt_himed.c -o wgt_himed.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--sort-common -o robustbase.so R-rng4ftn.o eigen.o init.o lmrob.o mc.o monitor.o qn_sn.o rf-common.o rffastmcd.o rfltsreg.o rllarsbi.o rob-utils.o rowMedians.o wgt_himed.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -lopenblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:6: robustbase.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘robustbase’
* removing ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6/robustbase’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘robustbase’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘kernlab’ ...
** package ‘kernlab’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c brweight.cpp -o brweight.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c ctable.cpp -o ctable.o
ctable.cpp: In member function ‘UInt32 ChildTable::up(const UInt32&, UInt32&)’:
ctable.cpp:60:9: warning: variable ‘lcp_idx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   60 |  UInt32 lcp_idx = 0, lcp_prev_idx = 0;
      |         ^~~~~~~
ctable.cpp:60:22: warning: variable ‘lcp_prev_idx’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   60 |  UInt32 lcp_idx = 0, lcp_prev_idx = 0;
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c cweight.cpp -o cweight.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dbreakpt.c -o dbreakpt.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dcauchy.c -o dcauchy.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dgpnrm.c -o dgpnrm.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dgpstep.c -o dgpstep.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dprecond.c -o dprecond.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dprsrch.c -o dprsrch.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dspcg.c -o dspcg.o
dspcg.c: In function ‘dspcg’:
dspcg.c:113:40: warning: variable ‘alpha’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  113 |  double gfnorm, gfnormf, stol = 1e-16, alpha;
      |                                        ^~~~~
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dtron.c -o dtron.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dtrpcg.c -o dtrpcg.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c dtrqsol.c -o dtrqsol.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c esa.cpp -o esa.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c expdecayweight.cpp -o expdecayweight.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c inductionsort.cpp -o inductionsort.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c init.c -o init.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c kspectrumweight.cpp -o kspectrumweight.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c lcp.cpp -o lcp.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c misc.c -o misc.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c msufsort.cpp -o msufsort.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c solvebqp.c -o solvebqp.o
x86_64-solus-linux-gcc -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -Wformat -Wformat-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c stringk.c -o stringk.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c stringkernel.cpp -o stringkernel.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c svm.cpp -o svm.o
svm.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* tron_optim(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
svm.cpp:3888:17: warning: variable ‘s’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 3888 |     const char* s;
      |                 ^
svm.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* smo_optim(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
svm.cpp:4189:17: warning: variable ‘s’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
 4189 |     const char* s;
      |                 ^
svm.cpp: In member function ‘void Solver_SPOC::Solve(int, const Kernel&, double*, short int*, double*, double, int, int)’:
svm.cpp:1435:12: warning: ‘q’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
 1435 |  int i, m, q, old_q = -1;
      |            ^
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c wkasailcp.cpp -o wkasailcp.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include  -fpic  -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g2 -pipe -fPIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong --param ssp-buffer-size=32 -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -ftree-vectorize -feliminate-unused-debug-types -Wall -Wno-error -Wp,-D_REENTRANT -fno-semantic-interposition -O3 -falign-functions=32  -c wmsufsort.cpp -o wmsufsort.o
x86_64-solus-linux-g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,max-page-size=0x1000 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,--sort-common -o kernlab.so brweight.o ctable.o cweight.o dbreakpt.o dcauchy.o dgpnrm.o dgpstep.o dprecond.o dprsrch.o dspcg.o dtron.o dtrpcg.o dtrqsol.o esa.o expdecayweight.o inductionsort.o init.o kspectrumweight.o lcp.o misc.o msufsort.o solvebqp.o stringk.o stringkernel.o svm.o wkasailcp.o wmsufsort.o -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lRlapack -lopenblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lopenblas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/usr/share/R/make/shlib.mk:6: kernlab.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘kernlab’
* removing ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6/kernlab’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kernlab’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘mclust’ is not available for package ‘prabclus’
* removing ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6/prabclus’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘prabclus’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘mclust’, ‘prabclus’, ‘robustbase’, ‘kernlab’ are not available for package ‘fpc’
* removing ‘/home/sandeep/R/x86_64-solus-linux-gnu-library/3.6/fpc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fpc’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmprJZWjh/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: The first error (`cannot find -lopenblas`) might be fixed if you install the `libopenblas-dev` (or just `libopenblas-base`) OS packages (debian/ubuntu flavor here) in order to support the openblas-dependent R packages. (Something like `apt-get install libopenblas-dev`.)

Comment: If you google the error Evans mentions, you should get hits like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353509/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lopenblas-error-in-caffe-compilation